# How to get all Shop Shipping methods Ids or Shipping zones in checkout page with liquid

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am trying to get all the store shipping methods Ids in Select shipping method page by modifying checkout.liquid

Or at least get the shipping_zones json in the same page.

I am talking about the IDs in /admin/api/2019-04/shipping_zones.json and I am using Shopify Plus.

I tried this script in the checkout.liquid layout but it returned an empty output I think this because the fact that a shipping method is still not added to the checkout object

```
  <script>
    <!-- DEBUG {{ checkout.shipping_method.title }} has been used -->
    {% if checkout.shipping_method.title == 'Pick-up at the store' %}
      Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
        `<p>Okay</p>`
      )
    {% endif %}
  </script>
```

I also tried this but didn't work either:

```
Shipping methods: <br>
{% for shipping_method in checkout.shipping_methods %}
* {{ shipping_method.title }}: {{ shipping_method.price | money }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help I really need this.

Answer (score 0):

You are Plus, so you get access to Shipping information using the Script Editor App. With that, you can setup your checkout to be as useful as possible. See the methods here: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/shopify-scripts#shipping-methods

It is really quite simple to hot-rod shipping using scripting. The best and usually only part of Plus I believe provides supreme value.

As a second solution if you cannot figure out how to manipulate Shipping from that Scripting, then use an App and that way you can control Shipping methods yourself. The Pro is you can do what you want, the con is you're responsible for your server being 24/7 ready to go, which is a hassle for a lot of merchants. If your shipping machine goes down, your checkouts go down too, which is why you want to maximize using Scripts in Plus

Comment: Use the right tools for the job. Using a JS callback is not the right thing to do. Shopify is giving you the right tool, you are choosing not to use it, and to cause yourself grief. Why?

Comment: Why are you fixated on the ID? If you don't need it, why ask for it? You want to monkey with Shipping Methods, you don't need an ID to do that.

Comment: Only a rookie would fixate on needing ID's instead of perhaps looking at the problem  with a more open mind, looking at the tools available, and solving the problem simply by choosing the right tools and data for the job. As I mentioned, good luck to you. I pointed out to you how to choose and perhaps even use the right tool, but you are stuck trying to kill your flies with a sledgehammer.

Comment: True.. that old it takes 10 rookies to match one old timer is a real thing. Mentoring is tough though, works best with minds open to learning new things without prejudice.